# What's the difference between using a router and a switch without management such as Tenda SG105?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Is it better to connect my wired devices directly into the router?
Or is a combination of the two the best, where I use a switch for printers, or other devices where only connectivity over speed is important, and plug everything else directly (somehow) in the router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, there is very little difference. "Speed" can go either way – using a switch does not automatically make things slower. (It might increase the *latency* a tiny bit though.) In fact, it could even make things *faster* if the switch is more capable than the router.

For example, if you have a router with 100 Mbps LAN ports, but a switch with 1 Gbps ports: Two devices connected to the switch would be able to communicate with each other at full 1 Gbps, while devices connected to the router would be limited to 100 Mbps only.

(A router sits between networks; it does not control communications within the same network. Packets between devices within the same subnet take the short path through switches and aren't looped back/forth through the router.)